# How can I render meta tags in html using vue-meta plugin?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-meta

I have laravel-vueJS application. I installed vue-meta plugin and declared metaInfo object in vue component as below,

```
metaInfo: {
    title: 'Default Title',
    description: 'Default description'
  },
```

These meta info is getting shown in front side but when I view the source code in browser it doesn't shows meta title and meta description.

The link to plugin: https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/
The section I want to accomplish: https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/guide/ssr.html#inject-metadata-into-page-string

1. How to render meta info in server side
2. What is the `server-entry.js` file mentioned in document.

Comment: i'm stuck at this point also. did you solve this?